# Session management in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testng

I have a class under which I have different methods one of them is login and other are related to the adding product to cart, checkout and shipping.
When I try to run the methods using TestNG in one go, it execute all the methods in different browsers session and I lost  my login session.
I want some solution so that either all the methods execute in same browser or I can use the session of login method in other consecutive methods
Thanks in advance

1. I have same login for both
2. I am creating new instance of driver in both methods

Here is my code :

public class purchase {

```
    @Test
    public void login(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "{path}/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver fd= new ChromeDriver();
        fd.get("{domain}/login/");
        /*{login script here}*/
    }
    @Test
    public void purchaseItem(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "{path}/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver fd1= new ChromeDriver();
        fd1.get("{domain}/travel");
        /*add item to cart*/
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you show us some of your work please?

Answer (score 0):

It means there might be 2 issue:
1. You have separate login in both the methods
2. You are creating new instance of driver in both methods.

Please share your code and will help you with resolving it.

Comment: Gaurav please check, I have added more detail above

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the same driver instance between methods. Otherwise, you will have a new session each time, like you described it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. as per your comment - "I am creating new instance of driver in both methods"..

So, if you want to maintain the session, you have to use a single instance of driver in both methods.

You can achieve it using beforeClass method (Use it for driver initializing and login), and write your logic in different test methods.. So it will make sure complete test cycle for the class is 1 and then your session will not be lost.

Let me know if this helps.